# Make HTML-checkbox into string before putting into form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if a html checkbox is checked and then create a variable to put into a form data object but i cannot make it work.

Javascript code

```
if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked){
  var isitchecked = "yes";
} else{ 
  var isitchecked = "no";
}

formdata_object = {
  "formcheckbox" : isitchecked.value
}
```

I have also tried with solution below but it does not work either

```
formdata_object = {
  "formcheckbox" : document.getElementById("checkbox").value
}
```

I dont know how to make the variable into a form data object. How do i continue? Do i even have the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply try this code snippet.

```
formdata_object = {
  "formcheckbox" : (document.getElementById("checkbox").checked ? 'yes' : 'no')
}
```

Comment: This seems like the easiest solution, i will try it and get back with the result

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>                
            </head>

            <body>
                <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox"     onchange="isChecked()">
                <script>
                function isChecked(){
                    var isitchecked ;
                    if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked){
                          isitchecked = "yes";
                        } else{ 
                          isitchecked = "no";
                        }

                        formdata_object = {
                          "formcheckbox" : isitchecked
                        }

                        console.log(formdata_object)
                }

                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

with jquery

```
           $(function(){
                    var isitchecked ;
                    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
                        if(this.checked){
                            isitchecked = "yes";
                        }else{
                            isitchecked = "no";
                        }
                        formdata_object = {
                          "formcheckbox" : isitchecked //
                        }
                        console.log(formdata_object)
                    });
                 });
```

Comment: I dont want to use the the HTML element of onchange beacuse of the architecture of my application